# Load Ruby on Rails models without loading the entire framework

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, daemon

I'm looking to create a custom daemon that will run various database tasks such as delaying mailings and user notifications (each notice is a separate row in the notifications table). I don't want to use `script/runner` or `rake` to do these tasks because it is possible that some of the tasks only require the create of one or two database rows or thousands of rows depending on the task. I don't want the overhead of launching a ruby process or loading the entire rails framework for each operation. I plan to keep this daemon in memory full time.

To create this daemon I would like to use my models from my ruby on rails application. I have a number of rails plugins such as `acts_as_tree` and `AASM` that I will need loaded if I where to use the models. Some of the plugins I need to load are custom hacks on ActiveRecord::Base that I've created. (I am willing to accept removing or recoding some of the plugins if they need components from other parts of rails.)

My questions are

- Is this a good idea?
- And - Is this possible to do in a way that doesn't have me manually including each file in my models and plugins?

If not a good idea

- What is a good alternative?

(I am not apposed to doing writing my own SQL queries but I would have to add database constraints and a separate user for the daemon to prevent any stupid accidents. Given my lack of familiarity with configuring a database, I would like to use active record as a crutch.)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your concern is that you don't want to pay the time- or memory- cost to spin up the rails stack every time your task needs to be run? If you plan on keeping the daemon running full-time, as you say, you can just daemonize a process that has loaded your rails stack and will only have to pay that memory- or time-related penalty for loading the stack one time, when the daemon starts up.

[Async_worker](http://github.com/kr/async-observer) is a good example of this sort of pattern: It uses beanstalk to pass messages to one or more worker processes that are each just daemons that have loaded the full rails stack.

One thing you have to pay attention to when doing this is that you'll need to restart your daemonized processes upon a deploy so they can reload your updated rails stack. I'm using this for a url-shortener app (the single async worker process I have running sits around waiting to save referral data after the visitor gets redirected), and it works well, I just have an `after:deploy` capistrano task that restarts any async worker(s).

Answer (score 0):

You can load up one aspect of Rails such as ActiveRecord but when you get right down to it the cost of loading the entire environment is not much more than just loading ActiveRecord itself. You could certainly just not include aspects like ActionMailer or some of the side bits but I'm going to guess that you're not going to see much win out of it.

What I would suggest instead is either running through runner/console like you said you didn't want to but rather than bootstrapping each time, try to batch things so that you're doing 1000 at a time instead of 1. There are a lot of projects that use this style, some of the bulk mailers spring to mind if you want examples. DJ (delayed_job) does similar by storing a bit in the database saying that this code needs to be run at some point in the future using the environment stack but it tries to batch together as much as it can so you may get win from that.

The other option is to have a persistent mini-rails app with as much stripped out as possible so that the memory usage is lower which can listen for requests and do your bidding when you want it to. This would be more memory but the latency of bootstrapping would be essentially nullified.

Lastly, as an afterthought, this would be a great use for Postgres.