# Partially load Rails app, without starting server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a separate script in my Rails app which is executed like a worker by Bunny (an AMQP client), I don't need to load the entire app. For instance I certainly won't need anything like Unicorn or any of the the routes, etc. I basically only need access to my models. Is this possible?

Right now the worker loads the entire rails app like this:

```
require ::File.expand_path('../config/environment', __FILE__)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Load only part of environment for rake task?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9779025/load-only-part-of-environment-for-rake-task)

Comment: Or maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1757689/load-ruby-on-rails-models-without-loading-the-entire-framework, but it doesn't have as actionable an answer. The first one seems likely to work...